# how to format format a piece of codes

Tags: monaco-editor

I know how to format the entire documents, but I am encounter a specific requirement that is how to format a piece of code that selected by the user.

As the ["Hello world" playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html) suggestion that we can select a piece of code and execute `Format Selection` context menu, but it's not work as expected.

Answer (score 10):

This question is fixed by myself, in case of someone may be encounter the issue I will give some detail explanation.

I am going to make a SQL editor which is not a built-in language.

If you try to make "Format Document" and "Format Selection" work, you need make some configuration for this custom language.

Here we go:

```js
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor';

// https://github.com/zeroturnaround/sql-formatter
import { format } from 'sql-formatter';

// define a document formatting provider
// then you contextmenu will add an "Format Document" action
monaco.languages.registerDocumentFormattingEditProvider('sql', {
  provideDocumentFormattingEdits(model, options) {
    var formatted = format(model.getValue(), {
      indent: ' '.repeat(options.tabSize)
    });
    return [
      {
        range: model.getFullModelRange(),
        text: formatted
      }
    ];
  }
});

// define a range formatting provider
// select some codes and right click those codes 
// you contextmenu will have an "Format Selection" action
monaco.languages.registerDocumentRangeFormattingEditProvider('sql', {
  provideDocumentRangeFormattingEdits(model, range, options) {
    var formatted = format(model.getValueInRange(range), {
      indent: ' '.repeat(options.tabSize)
    });
    return [
      {
        range: range,
        text: formatted
      }
    ];
  }
});
```

After those configuration you can:

```js
// mannually trigger document formatting by:
monacoEditor.trigger("editor", "editor.action.formatDocument");

// mannully tirgger selection formatting by:
monacoEditor.trigger("editor", "editor.action.formatSelection");
```

API reference:

- [registerDocumentFormattingEditProvider](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.languages.html#registerdocumentformattingeditprovider)
- [registerDocumentRangeFormattingEditProvider](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.languages.html#registerdocumentrangeformattingeditprovider)

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much! This also works when using @monaco-editor/react